# Универсальный метод парсинга Json

Tags: c#, .net, json, десериализация

Есть некий апи сервис который отдает Json объекты.

Сервис построен таким образом, что статс 200(OK) может вернуть нужный мне объект, а может вернуть объект ошибки следующего формата `{ "error": "<error message>" }`

```
public class ApiError
    {
        [JsonProperty("error")]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

Мне необходимо проверить какой именно объект вернул сервер, и вернуть `true or false` , а также свой обственный объект ошибки (он буде отличаться от вышеуказанного).

Вот мой пример кода

```
private bool IsError(out Error error)
        {
            var apiError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiError>(json);

            if (apiError.Message != null )
            {
                error = new Error(apiError.Message);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                error = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Проблема в том, что когда приходит не объект ошибки, приложение крашится с ошибкой сериализации. Я так понимаю нужен какойту универсальный метод

Comment: `try/catch`? а вообще странный сервер, если он на ошибку код 200 присылает

Comment: @tym32167 try / catch не подходит по идеологическим соображениям. Это еще норм бывало приходили ответы и в HTML

Comment: Т.е задача проверить в каком формате пришел ответ? В Html или Json?

Comment: @ iluxa1810, нет, формат известен - json (html - это я так к слову оветил, из личного опыта)

Comment: Все таки, чем не устраивает try/catch? Пытаетесь сериализовать как ошибку, не получилось? Значит, ошибки нет Можно через contains проверять строку  на похожесть на формат ошибки.

Comment: тогда разбирайте в JObject, смотрите, какие у него поля

Comment: try/catch будет возвращть exception - исключительные ситуации, а  мне приходит простой объект

Comment: @РоманТимохов так в блоке catch проглотите исключение и верните false-сериалиация не прошла, значит ошибки не было- зависит от вашей семантики.

Comment: @tym32167 в том то и дело что объект может прийти или тот что нужен  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json)` или `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiError>(json)`

Comment: @iluxa1810 не нужно меня переубеждать - вариант с try cetch не подходит

Comment: @РоманТимохов ну тогда разбирайте строку руками перед тем, как выполнить десериализацию.

Comment: @iluxa1810 вы имеете в виду RegExp маску прописать?

Comment: @РоманТимохов например да. Однако, возможно, вам хватит какого-нибудь Contains или Substring.

Comment: @iluxa1810 ок, спасибо, буду пробовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать спарсить в [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)

```
var ob =JObject.Parse("{ \"message\": \"<simple message>\" }");
var isError = ob.Properties().Any(x=>x.Name == "error");
Console.WriteLine(isError);

ob = JObject.Parse("{ \"error\": \"<error message>\" }");
isError = ob.Properties().Any(x => x.Name == "error");
Console.WriteLine(isError);
```

Вариант с [ContainsKey](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ContainsKey.htm)

```
var ob =JObject.Parse("{ \"message\": \"<simple message>\" }");
var isError = ob.ContainsKey("error");
Console.WriteLine(isError);

ob = JObject.Parse("{ \"error\": \"<error message>\" }");
isError = ob.ContainsKey("error");
Console.WriteLine(isError);
```

Comment: вероятно [.ContainsKey](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_ContainsKey.htm) можно было использовать

Comment: @Grundy спс, добавил

Comment: в общем так все заработало: `private bool IsError(out Error error)
        {
            if (JObject.Parse(json).ContainsKey("error"))
            {
                var apiError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiError>(json);
                error = new Error(apiError.Message);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                error = null;
                return false;
            }
        }`

Comment: @РоманТимохов зачем дважды парсить? Мессадж вы вот так можете вытащить `ob.Property("error").Value`

Comment: @ tym32167  спасибо,  исправил

Comment: @РоманТимохов, а еще есть метод [`.ToObject<T>`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm)

Comment: @Grundy вы определенно знаете больше меня, вам над было ответ писать, я сам то этот JObject не юзал никогда )

Comment: @Grundy, tym32167 спасибо за подсказки. Пополнил знания. iluxa1810, ваше решение тоже рабочее, но меня больше интерсовал вариант реализация с помощью Json.Net

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант выполнить десериализация не нарвавшись на исключение- это выполнить ручную проверку того, что строка подходит по формату целевого объекта.

Например, воспользовавшись строковой функция `Contains` проверить, есть ли в строке поле еrror или нет.

Однако, я ничего не вижу ничего плохого, что бы получать и обрабатывать исключение.

Comment: какое-то совсем не тривиальное решение будет